# Inequality : $ \sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}} \geq 2 \sqrt{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals, sum-of-squares-method, holder-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that: 
>   $$ \displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}} \geq 2 \sqrt{a+b+c}.$$

My attempt :

By Holder inequality,

$ \left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}}\right)^2 \displaystyle\sum_{cyc}(a+2c)\geq \left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b}\right)^3$

$ \left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}}\right)^2 \geq \frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b}\right)^3}{\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}(a+2c)}$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}}\right)^2 \geq \frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b}\right)^3}{3\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}a}$

$\Leftrightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b}\right)^3}{3\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}a}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to use Holder was very good!

By Holder $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a+2c}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(a+2c)\geq8(a+b+c)^3.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$8(a+b+c)^3\geq4(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(a+2c)$$ or
$$2(a+b+c)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(a+2c),$$ which is
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: On the second line, shouldn't it be $8(a+b+c)^3$ rather than $8(a+b+c)^2$ ?

Comment: Thank you dear  @Ewan Delanoy! I fixed my post.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @carat You are welcome!